# How to plot mutiple variable plots in same dygraph in R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dygraphs, r-dygraphs

I have included the dataset please look into it

```
>temp
   date_time     value1 value2
1 2018-07-01   0.12   0.13
2 2018-07-02   0.24   0.15
3 2018-07-03   0.33   0.16
4 2018-07-04   0.40   0.18
5 2018-07-05   0.48   0.19
6 2018-07-06   0.67   0.20
>str(temp)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date_time: Date, format: "2018-07-01" "2018-07-02" ...
 $ value1   : num  0.12 0.24 0.33 0.4 0.48 0.67
 $ value2   : num  0.13 0.15 0.16 0.18 0.19 0.2

 dygraph(temp, main = "value1 vs value2") %>%
      dySeries(temp$value1, drawPoints = TRUE, pointShape = "square", color = "blue") %>%dySeries(temp$value2, stepPlot = TRUE, fillGraph = TRUE, color = "red")
```

I am getting the following error as below:

```
Error in dygraph(temp, main = "value1 vs value2") : 
  Unsupported type passed to argument 'data'.
```

can Anyone tell me like how to plot the two variables value1 and value2 in the same Dygraph with time series date along x-axis..?? or if its not possible can anyone suggest this using plotly too...?

Comment: You don't provide a reproducible so it's hard to tell. You could try this: `dygraph( xts(x = temp, order.by = date_time), main = "value1 vs value2") %>%...`

Comment: Thanks for the help it works,and can you tell me in plotly too..?

Comment: [this](https://plot.ly/r/line-charts/) will show you how to do it with `plotly`.